# How much of a library is included?

Tags: atlas

Just some basic question regarding C and the compiler.

I am planning on using the ATLAS library, however I will only ever use two or three algorithms from there.  Is it so that if I include just one header then will just that header be built and my SW will not grow too large?  Or is it so that the whole ATLAS library will be included?  So maybe better just to cut and paste that algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `#include` directive, the entirety of that header file is literally pasted into your document. The `#include` is recursive though, i.e. it nests (up to 256 levels), so whatever is `#include`d in the file you include is also included. To give an example:

## `yourprogram.c`, `lib1.h`, and `lib2.h`

```
/* yourprogram.c */
#include <lib1.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello, world.");
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
/* lib1.h */
#include <lib2.h>

void function1(void);
void function2(void);
```

---

```
/* lib2.h */

void function3(void);
void function4(void);
```

## After preprocessing

```
/* yourprogram.c (after preprocessing) */

void function3(void);    
void function4(void);

void function1(void);
void function2(void);

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello, world.");
    return 0;
}
```